# Program outputs only partial linked list instead of the entire linked list

Tags: javascript, arrays, linked-list, console.log

Im converting arrays into linked lists and linked lists into arrays. My issue is that I get the incorrect console log of the linked list I make, but the correct console log of the array created from that linked list.

In the code below, I get the expected output of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] from listToArray(). But w/ arrayToList(), my output is 
{ value: 1, rest: { value: 2, rest: { value: 3, rest: [Object] } } }. What happened to values 4 and 5? They should be there because in this case, listToArray() uses an identical list created from arrayToList().

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

var arrayToList = function(arr) {
  var list = {};
  var head = list;

  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
    list.value = arr[i];
    list.rest = {};

    if (i == arr.length - 1) {
      list = null;
    } else {
      list = list.rest;
    }
  }

  return head;
}

var listToArray = function(list) {
  var arr = [];
  var index = 0;

  while(list.rest != null) {
    arr[index] = list.value;
    list = list.rest;
    index += 1;
  }

  return arr;
}

console.log(listToArray(arrayToList(array)));
console.log(arrayToList(array));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you running in a browser or Node.js? Different environments have different console behavior. In Node when you do `console.log(someObject)` it will call [`util.inspect`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) to convert your Object to a String. The default recursion depth of `util.inspect` is 2 and after that it will just show `[Object]`.

You can try

```
console.log(util.inspect({depth: null}));
```

Comment: You're amazing. Thank you for the help! Case closed

Comment: Great insight! I am trying to do the same in vscode console. It errs out saying it does not understand 'util'. Any idea how I can call the function that prints my linked list in vscode console?

Comment: util isn't loaded by default there but you can use `console.log(require('util').inspect(...`. There might be some way to preload it by editing `launch.json` in vscode but I couldn't figure it out.